# Chi square test in a contigency table with sampling zeroes

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

im trying to estimate if an association exists between two variables in a 7x5 contingency table (the type of prosthesis with the type of complication). The table contains a lot of sampling zeroes and several sample values are small. I cannot increase the sample or pool variables. The table is:

```
              Complication 1    Comp 2  Comp 3  Comp 4    Comp 5  
Prosthesis 1          6         19        9       7         1     
Prosthesis 2          6         5         2       0         0     
Prosthesis 3          5         3         0       0         0     
Prosthesis 4          1         0         0       0         0     
Prosthesis 5          3         0         0       0         0     
Prosthesis 6          1         0         0       0         0     
Prosthesis 7          2         3         0       0         0
```

Is there a way to perform a chi square test of independence in this table?
Is it a valid strategy to replace zeroes with some constant small number like 0.000001?

Comment: Why would you want to do that replacement?  It won't change the $\chi^2$ statistic by much.  Having zeros in a table is not a problem, nor is having small sample values.  What matters is having a sizable proportion of small *expected* values (which is the case here).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I know there is something that i haven't got right here. I thought that i cant use a chi square for values < 5 and neither a fisher's test for a 5x7 table. I was looking for a solution and i ve seen an extract from "The analysis of contigency tables 2nd ed". It was mentioned that for empty cells due to sampling (as is my case) and not structural zeroes to either increase the sample size (which i cannot do) or add a small positive constant in all cells like 0.5. So i can use a chi square analysis for this table it will be valid? Thanks again.

Comment: It makes no sense to alter the cells, which must be integral counts in the first place.  That suggestion suggests you would benefit from reviewing what the chi-squared test is and how it works.  In this case many people would elect to test the association using a permutation test or (even though, strictly speaking, it's not applicable) Fisher's Exact Test (which essentially is a permutation test too).